# How to destroy an activity in Android and start with initial settings?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

While the application is running, I press the HOME button to close the application. When I start the application again, it resumes or not reseted some values for example i'm using initTTS() this is text to speech when i start the application over again i hear some speech like he remember the last action and it happen when i close and start the application on the android device if i start the application from the android-stido with my device it's starting from the beginning like everything is reseted i wonder why when i close my application from the device and start it again it remember some of the last actions. I want the application to start with the initial settings instead. I have used finish() to finish the activity but it is not working. Any ideas ?

For example this my top of the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";
    private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
        "http://192.168.1.5:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
    private String iptouse = "";
    private TextView text;
    private boolean connectedtoipsuccess = false;
    private int counter = 0;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private TextView text1, text2, text3;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private TextView timerValue;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    private int servercheckCounter = 0;
    private byte[] checkServer = null;
    private boolean connectedSuccess = false;
    private TextView status, status1;
    private TextView uploadedfilescount;
    private int numberofuploadedfilescounter = 0;

    String a = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        serverChecksThread.start();
        status1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        uploadedfilescount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberofuploadedFiles);
        uploadedfilescount.setText("Uploaded Files: 0")
        addListenerOnButton();
        initTTS();
    }
```

And this is a sample of solution i saw:

```
public class MyRootActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG=MyRootActivity.class.getName();
    private static ArrayList<Activity> activities=new ArrayList<Activity>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activities.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        activities.remove(this);
    }

    public static void finishAll()
    {
        for(Activity activity:activities)
           activity.finish();
    }
}
```

Quote: " For that all of your activities need to be children of MyRootActivity.

Then when you are about to sure that you're closing your application - just call MyRootActivity.finishAll(); "

I didn't understand how and where do i implant this Activity in my MainActivity.
How do i make sure(know) when i close my application ? 
And where do i call the MyRootActivity.finishAll(); ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to keep the historical trace for the activity when user navigates away from that activity.

For that you can set the flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" in intent from where you are starting your activity. Like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

or set `android:noHistory="true"` in manifest for that activity.

From developer docs :

> android:noHistory : 
>       Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user
>   navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true"
>   if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is
>   "false".
>
> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the
>   task, so the user will not be able to return to it.

Comment: I didn't understand where do i put the Intent instance line and the addFlags line. What i did now is added the instance line right after the MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity line before all the privates vars and the line intent.addFlags i added inside the onCreate after the line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but that make my program to crash. So i guess i didn't add this lines in the current place.

Comment: Just add android:noHistory=true in manifest, where you have declared your activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep *any* state when the user leaves an activity, then @abhishesh is right, you should use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag and your activity will be recreated every time as though it had never been called before.

Alternately, you can override `onPause` and `onResume` in your activity, to get more control over what is reset when you leave and return to an activity, respectively. For your TTS issue, for example, you could (and probably should) retain a reference to your `TextToSpeech` object, and call `shutdown()` on it in your `onPause` method.

If you move your `initTTS()` method to `onResume`, this will mean that your TTS should stop whenever you navigate away from the activity, and should start from the beginning when you return. If you leave it in `onCreate`, it will stop when you move away from the activity, and will not start again until the Activity is destroyed by the system, which is impossible to predict perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it add to your manifest launchMode="singleTask"

```
<activity
         android:name=".MainActivity" 
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:launchMode="singleTask"
         >
```

every time when user press on icon app its start like new app and automatically destroy all other activities on background besides situation when user come back to app via task manager.